# Настройка хлебных крошек в Битрикс

Tags: php, javascript, битрикс

Добрый день!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Последний элемент хлебных крошек на карточке товаров (название товара) дублирует содержимое h1. 
Сейчас H1 и название товара в хлебных крошках берутся из раздела SEO. Нужно чтобы последний элемент брался из поля Название товара.

Например: Сейчас в хлебных крошках и H1 - Купить желтое кресло 
Должно быть: H1 - Купить желтое кресло, в крошках - Желтое кресло

Как решить эту проблему?

Код вывода крошек:

```
<?php 
if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die(); 

/** 
* @global CMain $APPLICATION 
*/ 

global $APPLICATION; 

//delayed function must return a string 
if(empty($arResult)) 
return ""; 

$strReturn = ''; 

$strReturn .= '<span class="B_crumbBox">'; 

$itemSize = count($arResult); 
for($index = 0; $index < $itemSize; $index++) 
{ 
$title = htmlspecialcharsex($arResult [$index]["TITLE"]); 

if($arResult[$index]["LINK"] <> "" && $index != $itemSize-1) 
{ 
$strReturn .= ' 
<span class="B_firstCrumb"> 
<a href="'.$arResult[$index]["LINK"].'" title="'.$title.'" itemprop="url" class="B_homeCrumb">'.$title.'</a> 
</span> » '; 
} 
else 
{ 
$strReturn .= ' 
<span class="B_lastCrumb"> 
<span class="B_currentCrumb">'.$title.'</span> 
</span>'; 
} 
} 

$strReturn .= '</span>'; 
return $strReturn;
```

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, на странице товара ДО вывода "крошек" присваивать некоей уникальной переменной Название товара

```
$unique_variable = $arItem['NAME'] /**или как оно там выводится..*/;
```

а внутри компонента "крошек" выводить

```
global $unique_variable;

$strReturn .= ' 
<span class="B_lastCrumb"> 
<span class="B_currentCrumb">'.$unique_variable.'</span> 
</span>';
```

Конечно, хорошо бы заранее создать и править специальный шаблон "крошек" конкретно для использования на странице товара детально.